# Bash Script for printing the modified files in Summary and Verbose mode?

Tags: linux, bash

This is my code till now. I have used "find" and mtime to recurively find the list of modified files.

```
baseFile=$1;
mtime=$2;
outputmode=$3;
if [ $outputmode = 1 ]
    then 
        find  $1/ -type f -mtime $2 | ls -lh
    fi
if [ $outputmode = 2 ]
    then
        echo $USER
        find  $1/ -type f -mtime $2 | wc -l

    fi
```

This program accepts input during execution. the syntax is ./filename.sh param1 param2 param3

param1- path of the directory within which the modified files have to be found.

param2- value for the "mtime" parameter

param3-accepts 2 values

value 1 output should be like this(summary mode)

```
Owner      Number of files changes
 sh             3
```

value 2 out should be like this (verbose mode)

```
sh
w------- 1 sh sh 1998 Feb 8 20:30 a.m
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sh sh 45000 Feb 8 20:29 a.txt
-rw-rw-r-- 1 sh sh 45000 Feb 8 20:29 b.txt
```

$1 is for param 1 and $2 is for param 2.

The summary and verbose modes are based on the third parameter as indicated by $3

My code just prints the modified files and the total count of files in that given particular directory.
As for the verbose mode my code just prints the directories but i need to print only the modified files
Any help for this would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you set the variables `baseFile` and `mtime`, then use `$1` and `$2` later in the script instead of those variables?

Comment: as i have stated in the question,i accept the inputs while compiling.hence i have replaced basefile as $1 and mtime which is just a variable as $2.you can replace that with any variable.sorry for the confusion

Comment: You're confusing argument lists with standard input. Filenames have to be arguments. Why don't you just use the `-exec` option to `find`?

Comment: I know that. I"m just wondering why you didn't write `find $baseName/` instead of `find $1/`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ls` gets filename arguments from their argument list, not standard input. You can use `xargs` to convert standard input to arguments

```
find "$baseFile"/ -type f -mtime "$mtime" -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lh
```

The `-print0` and `-0` options work together to ensure that this works properly even if filenames have whitespace (which otherwise would cause them to be treated as multiple arguments).

Or you can just use the `-exec` option:

```
find "$baseFile"/ -type f -mtime "$mtime" -exec ls -lh {} +
```

Comment: The 1st find operation is listing all the files and subdirectories.

The 2nd find operation is not showing the number of files modified.

The aim is to do these both only for the modified files.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the question. Your `wc` is correct if you just want to count the number of changed files.

Comment: Thanks,but they both list everything in that directory including the subdirectories and files.
How to do this only for the modified files ?

Comment: Do you get the correct files if you don't pipe it to `ls`?

Comment: What `mtime` value are you giving?

Comment: mtime value -1 . any value for mtime , all files are getting listed

Comment: It works fine for me. I had an incorrect variable in my answer before, I just fixed it.

Comment: I had `$baseName` when it should have been `$baseFile`. So it was searching `/` instead of the directory in the argument.

Comment: If I use `mtime = -1` it just shows 2 files, if I use `mtime = -30` it shows 7 files.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you use the `find` command by hand instead of in the script?